# Need to check for any 500

Tags: backbone.js

I have an interesting dilemma. I am using backbone js to build the front end of a "real time" app. This app will check for alerts every 15 seconds, the problem is that some times the system gets overloaded - and will throw a verity of 5xx error messages or 103 errors.

What we want to do is say:

```
if 5xx || 103
  do something.
else
  do something else.
```

What I have one, it try with 500, so I have the following:

```
failedToPoll: function(collection, response) {
    if (response.status === 500 || response.status === 103) {

        if (this.refresh_interval < this.ONE_MINUTE) {
            this.refresh_interval = this.ONE_MINUTE;
        } else if (this.refresh_interval < 180000) {
            this.refresh_interval = this.refresh_interval + this.ONE_MINUTE;
        }

        this.poll();

    } else {

        if (this.refresh_interval < this.ONE_MINUTE) {
            this.refresh_interval = this.refresh_interval + 5000;
        }

        this.poll();
    }
},
```

So this states that if we fail to pole, is it a 500  or 103, if so are we less then one minute - yes, lets up that - then poll again (after one minute). if we are greater then a minute and a 500 or 103, increase by 60 seconds till were 180 seconds.

If we are not 103 or 500, increase by 5 seconds to a maximum of 1 minute - every time the poll fails.

The problem?

it should read, **if we are 5xx (any 500 error message) or 103 do x.**

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (((status >= 500) && (status <= 599)) || (status == 103))
```